# How can I set the ForeignKey value in the view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My User registration form contains a ForeignKeyField and I am trying to set the value of this ForeignKeyField in the view. As can be seen in the code below, I am passing a parameter "pk" to the view and this parameter is for setting the ForeignKeyField value before the form is rendered, but this doesn't seem to work. After posting the form I get this error "(1048, "Column 'package_id' cannot be null")".

Here is my View.

```
def subscribe_view(request, billing_cycle, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userRegForm = CustomUserForm(request.POST)
        companyForm = CompanyProfileForm(request.POST)

        if userRegForm.is_valid() and companyForm.is_valid():
            user = userRegForm.save()
            compProfile = companyForm.save(commit=False)
            if compProfile.user_id is None:
                compProfile.user_id = user.id
            compProfile.save()

            selected_provinces = companyForm.cleaned_data['provinces']
            selected_cats = companyForm.cleaned_data['tenderCategory']
            selected_package = companyForm.cleaned_data['package']

            for province_item in selected_provinces:
                compProfile.provinces.add(province_item)

            for cat_item in selected_cats:
                compProfile.tenderCategory.add(cat_item)

            keyword_ids_str = companyForm.cleaned_data['keywordListItem']
            if keyword_ids_str is not '' or keyword_ids_str is not None:
                keyword_ids = keyword_ids_str.split(',')[:-1]
                for keyword_id in keyword_ids:
                    keywordObj = Keywords.objects.get(id=int(keyword_id.strip()))
                    compProfile.keywords.add(keywordObj)

            compProfile.package(selected_package)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_account/dashboard')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
    else:
        packageOption = Packages.objects.get(id=pk)

        if billing_cycle == '1' or billing_cycle == '0':
            b_cycle = billing_cycle
        else:
            b_cycle = '0'

        userRegForm = CustomUserForm()
        companyProfileForm = CompanyProfileForm(initial={'package': packageOption.id})
        bankingDetailsForm = BankingDetailsForm()

        #companyProfileForm.fields["package"].initial = packageOption.id

        args = {'userRegForm': userRegForm,
                'package': packageOption,
                'billing_cycle': b_cycle,
                'companyProfileForm': companyProfileForm,
                'bankingDetailsForm': bankingDetailsForm
        }
        args.update(csrf(request))
        return render(request, 'user_account/subscribe.html', args)
```

Here is Model:

```
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    companyName = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    companyRegNum = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    contactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    areaCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    deliveryEmails = models.TextField(blank=True)   #this is the list of all the people chosen to recieve daily notification.
    tenderCategory = models.ManyToManyField(category, blank=False)    #links the user to the chosen category.
    provinces = models.ManyToManyField(Province, blank=False)    #links the user to the chosen Provinces.
    package = models.ForeignKey(Packages, blank=False)       #links the user to the chosen package.
    pymntMethod = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=3)   #this is the chosen payment method (e.g credit card=1, debit order=2 or direct debit=3)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keywords)     #links the user to the chosen keywords.
    extraKeywords = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)  #this field acts as a container of extra keywords from the user. These are keywords that we do not have in our database.
    termsAndConditions = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=1)   #this is the T&C's field that must be agreed to by the client.
    commencementDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.companyName
```

Here is my form.

```
class CompanyProfileForm(ModelForm):
    provinces = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Province.objects.all(), widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
        'id': 'provinces'
    }))

    tenderCategory = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=category.objects.all(), widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
        'id': 'catSelect'
    }))

    keywordListItem = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={
        'id': 'keywordListItem_id'
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyProfile
        exclude = (
            'user',
            'keywords',
            'commencementDate',
            'package',
        )
        fields = (
            'companyName',
            'companyRegNum',
            'contactNumber',
            'address',
            'areaCode',
            'deliveryEmails',
            'provinces',
            'tenderCategory',
            'termsAndConditions',
        )

        widgets = {
            'companyName': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'id': 'companyNameId',
                            'name': 'companyName',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter company name'
                        }),
            'companyRegNum': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'id': 'companyRegNumId',
                            'name': 'companyRegNum',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter company reg number'
                        }),
            'contactNumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control input_field',
                            'id':'contactNum',
                            'name': 'contactNumber',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter contact number'
                        }),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'id': 'addressId',
                            'name': 'address',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter the address'
                        }),
            'areaCode': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control',
                            'id': 'areaCodeId',
                            'name': 'areaCode',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter the areaCode'
                        }),
            'deliveryEmails': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                            'class': 'form-control textInput',
                            'id': 'deliveryEmailId',
                            'name': 'deliveryEmails',
                            'required': 'required',
                            'data-rule-required': 'true',
                            'data-msg-required': 'Please enter the email address(s)'
                        }),

            'package': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'pymntMethod': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={
                            'id': 'pymntType',
                            'value': '3'
                        }),
            'termsAndConditions': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
                            'id': 'termsAndConditions'
                        })
        }
```

does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Well, you exclude the field from the form, so passing it in will have no effect. But why can't you do the same with package as you do with user - ie set it on save?

Comment: Including the field in the form makes no difference, I still get the same error.

Comment: I didn't say to include it, I said to set it on save.

Comment: Solved it, the error was caused by an internal server error. for some reason by introducing the "default" attribute in the ForeignKey solves the problem.

Comment: Pretty sure you haven't solved the problem. Introducing the "default" attribute *would* avoid the error, but only because you'll always set the default value. You still aren't setting the package correctly, unless you always want it to be the default value.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that might be contributing to what you're running into:

1. `package` is listed as a `ForeignKey` field that does not have `null=True` set, meaning it's a required field. As such, there needs to be a value before the model instance is saved. The reason setting a `default` attribute fixed that error is that you're now providing a value other than `null` for it. If this is a field that can allow null, update the model to include `null=True`, and make sure to make a migration to update your database, then try this again.
2. When updating the `package`, I'm noticing that the package to be assigned is being passed to it like it's a method. I'm not aware that this is valid, since attributes are usually updated by direct assignment (`compProfile.package = selected_package`).
3. When updating the attribute for a model instance (`compProfile` is a model instance of `CompanyProfile`), any changes to that instance's attributes are not persisted to the database unless `save()` is called. This means that if it were fetched from the database later, the `package` would not match what was assigned. Make sure that `compProfile.save()` is called after modifying it.